# Upload new iOS binary without a release

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I just submitted a new version of my application (version 2.0) to Apple and it is Waiting For Review in the App Store. I set it to release manually as we are strategically planning a release.

We have a more feature filled version of the app (2.1) ready but we want to make sure the first version passes Apple review first.

My question is, once Apple accepts 2.0 are we going to be able to upload 2.1 without releasing 2.0 live into the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two unreleased versions at the same time.

When you have only a version that's live on the app store, the iTunes Connect UI shows these buttons:

[image: New Version]

When you have a version pending developer release (or waiting for review, or otherwise not on the store), the iTunes Connect UI shows these buttons:

[image: Release This Version]

As a result, you do not have the option to create a new 2.1 version without pushing 2.0 live on the store.

Answer (score 1):

You will see two statuses - one for 2.0 that will be green once it is approved and on the store, and one for 2.1 that will be yellow - waiting for review.  You can always have a live binary and one waiting for review :)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you will be fine. No need to release 2.0 :)